# SQL query to count number of rows with same value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

I have this table data:

[image]

I want to perform an sql query which will give me the total number of distinct loan applications per city.

So for example, I would expect this output

```
City Wexford
Loans 1

City Waterford 1 
Loans 1

City Galway
Loans 3
```

Any idea what kind of query I need to perform to get the count of distinct loans for each city?

Comment: I am noticing that the LoanApplicationID is not unique to a City. So for example LoanApplicationID 3380 appears both for Dublin 8 and Galway City ? is this accurate data?

Comment: What have you tried so far????

Comment: @DaniDev one application can have multiple properites, one in Dublin 8 and one in Galway City for example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would guess, probably a COUNT (Distinct ID) with GROUP BY. Something like this:

```
SELECT city, COUNT(DISTINCT LoanApplicationID) as Loans
FROM tableName
GROUP BY city
```

Comment: @Laziale then you should think about accepting that answer. It rewards the answerer and it prevents others to go into this solved question while other questions still need help

Comment: @Laziale Please see my comment in OP. How is it that LoanApplicationID is not unique to a City? Would this affect your desired results?

Comment: @Laziale, Reason for my question is that this solution will count such an applicationID twice. Once For each CityProperty. So am wondering if the query needs to account for this or not?

Comment: @DaniDev It should count distinct cities per loan, not per property. Please let me know if some adjustments are needed. Thanks

Comment: your OP says "I .....total number of distinct loan applications per city. "   which is what this answer provides. However there is a caveat that the same loan could be counted (twice or more) as it can be applied to different City(s). So there is a question whether thst is the result you are after. 
your above statement "It should count distinct cities per loan" is a different query altogether. Please clarify what you mean?

Answer (score -1):

Here is another approach for this question. I am adding this because using `DISTINCT` may cause performance issues for another example, especially for large databases. Good to keep in mind.

```
select city,count(LoanApplicationID) as Loans
from (
        select LoanApplicationID, city
        from tablename
        group by LoanApplicationID, city 
     ) t
group by city
```